# List View Sliding Window

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of numbers and I'd like to select a sliding window of a certain size:

```
List<double> lst = {3,78,24,25,634,25,478,24};
int WindowSize = 4;

index = 0: return {3};
index = 1: return {3,78};
index = 2: return {3,78,24};
index = 3: return {3,78,24,25};
index = 4: return {78,24,25,634};
index = 5: return {24,25,634,25};
index = 6: return {25,634,25,478};
index = 7: return {634,25,478,24};
```

This isn't that hard of a concept, but I'm trying to do it with the `.Skip() .Take()` extension methods.  Is there an easier way to select the `WindowSize` entries before an item instead of trying to find where the starting point is and then getting the next `WindowSize` entries?  I'm trying to think of an easier way to do this with linq than having all the bounds checking that is required with `Skip()` and `Take()`.

You could reverse the list and then do a Count() - index and then a Take() but that doesn't seem efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess this would require minimal bound checking - just basic sanity checks. See if this works

```
IEnumerable<double> GetWindow(List<double> lst, int index, int windowSize) {
    if(index >= lst.Length){
        // Throw proper exception
    }
    return lst.Skip(index-windowSize).Take(Math.Min(index,windowSize));
}
```

Comment: you can simply use Skip(index-windowSize), negative values are simply ignored and treated as 0

Comment: @Alexander Yes you are right - I missed it. Corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to get one window, your accepted answer looks appropriate.
But for iterating more than one window, I would go with something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<TSource>> Window<TSource>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, int size)
{
    var q = new Queue<TSource>(size);

    foreach (var value in source)
    {
        if (q.Count >= size)
            q.Dequeue();
        q.Enqueue(value);
        yield return q;
    }
}
```